# ¿Existe una palabra para referirse a algo que es de oro, como para la plata existe argentino?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Según,

[RAE](https://dle.rae.es/argentino)

> argentino: adj. argénteo.
>
> argénteo: que es de plata.

¿Cómo sería una palabra equivalente para aquello que es de oro? Por las dudas busqué dorado: [Dorado Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=dorado%20significado&ei=0VIGY6-oAtXh1sQPifCLqAw&ved=0ahUKEwjv1Ljp89_5AhXVsJUCHQn4AsUQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=dorado%20significado&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAEIAEEEYQ-QEyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjoHCAAQRxCwAzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOggIABCABBCxAzoECAAQQzoECC4QQzoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoHCAAQsQMQQzoHCC4QsQMQQzoKCC4QsQMQ1AIQQzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOgUILhCABDoICAAQHhAPEBY6CAgAEB4QFhAKSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUOoDWMkVYLsXaANwAXgAgAHXAYgBqROSAQYwLjE3LjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) y una de las definiciones se le acerca,

> Que esta cubierto por una capa de oro.

Pero estar cubierto con una capa de oro no es lo mismo que ser de oro.

¿Existe una palabra para referirse a algo que es de oro, como para la plata existe argentino?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*áureo*

Según [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/%C3%A1ureo?m=form):

> 1. adj. De oro.

Answer (score 5):

Palabra desusada, de acuerdo con el DRAE:

> **tíbar**
>
> Del ár. hisp. tíb[a]r, y este del ár. clás. tibr 'oro'.
>
> 1. adj. desus. De oro puro.

Comment: Esta no me la esperaba y me ha encantado. En textos del CORDE he visto que a principios del siglo XVII se usaba como sustantivo: "cabellos de tíbar", "mejor que el nácar y el tíbar".

Answer (score 3):

Menos usado que *áureo*, pero también disponible:

> **[áurico, ca](https://dle.rae.es/%C3%A1urico?m=30_2)**
>
> 1. adj. De oro.

Comment: Encontré una tercera palabra, a ver si alguien la responde

Answer (score 3):

### Aurífero, ra

> Del lat. aurĭfer, -ĕri.
> 1. adj. Que lleva o contiene oro.

<sub>*[RAE](https://dle.rae.es/aur%C3%ADfero)*</sub>

### Aurino

> Adjetivo. Este término es de uso bastante inusual, inclusive anticuado, (en historia natural) que alude lo que es de oro y que participa en la naturaleza, así en las cualidades y características que la posee.
> Este vocablo en su etimología es de procedencia latina bajo denominación «aurĭnus» o de «aurĭnus deus» que quiere decir el Dios del oro.

<sub>*Fuente [definiciona.com](https://definiciona.com/aurino/)*</sub>

Comment: Mi comentario puede considerarse una cuestión de matices. Sin embargo, en mi humilde opinión si algo "lleva oro" o "contiene oro", no es exactamente lo mismo que un material "que es de oro". Precisamente porque si contiene oro, esto implica necesariamente que una parte de dicho objeto "no es de oro".